# change thumbnail attribute in wordpress?

Tags: html, wordpress

Is it possible to change the value of the `src` attribute to another value, and insert the original `src` value attribute into the new `data-src` attribute with `the_post_thumbnail()` function ?
Understood? I want to change this

```
<img src="img url">
```

to

```
<img src="another image" data-src="img url">
```

Thank you

Comment: see the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For the attribute**

Read carefully wordpress documentation.

[https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/)

> the_post_thumbnail( string|array $size = 'post-thumbnail', string|array
>   $attr = '' )

```
the_post_thumbnail( $size, $attr );
```

**You can change the image url with jquery.**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

      $("#dummyimage").attr("src","http://via.placeholder.com/350x150");


  });
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"
  integrity="sha256-Qw82+bXyGq6MydymqBxNPYTaUXXq7c8v3CwiYwLLNXU="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<img id="dummyimage" src="http://via.placeholder.com/550x350" data-src="img url" />
```